# How to get data from web page and preview them in my html page?

Tags: html

i need to get some data from external web page (specific text between  and  tags in this web page source code ) 
and then show this data in my html.

or get part of html code of another page 
then put it in my html page by a button click for examle

Comment: Please explain in greater detail what you want to achieve and sgow us some code you have so far.

Comment: this is external site http://www.goal.com/en/matches
i need to get some text data from it and show in my html page 
could it happen ?

Comment: @randomperson That's not possible in JavaScript, due to CORS restrictions, unless you use a proxy.

Comment: so it possible in what ?
is there any method to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard if it's somebody else's web page due to CORS. However, you should be able to if it's your web site.

1. Use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the page content.
2. Set the container element's `.innerHTML` to the textual representation of the HTML.

Comment: If you've got a hard-on for jquery, the .load() function makes this very easy. https://api.jquery.com/load/